# Centos/directadmin Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql

```
Error connecting to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I get the following error on my CentOS VM with DirectAdmin.

What I already tried:
Restarting the service, killing the services and starting, modifying the /etc/my.cnf file

Currently I completely removed my my.cnf file because mysqld starts without errors, if I add my.cnf file then I get the following error:

```
Starting MySQL.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/hostname.pid).
```

When I go look at `/var/lib/mysql/hostname.pid` there's no such file.

2 my.cnf files which I tried:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 4
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
thread_concurrency = 4
thread_cache_size = 4
table_cache = 256
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_limit = 1M
join_buffer_size = 256K
tmp_table_size = 256M
key_buffer = 32M
innodb_autoextend_increment=256
max_allowed_packet = 16M
max_heap_table_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256k
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 32M
myisam_repair_threads = 1
interactive_timeout=30
wait_timeout=30
binlog_cache_size=256M
tmpdir=/tmp
max_connections = 400
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

key_buffer_size=64M
```

original my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

---

EDIT:

I'm using the original my.cnf, deleted both .pid and .sock, after reboot I get the following:

```
[root@server ~]# service mysqld status
 ERROR! MySQL is not running, but PID file exists
[root@server ~]# service mysqld status
 ERROR! MySQL is running but PID file could not be found
```

Quite strange that it suddently starts running even though I didn't do any other command then what you see above. When looking at `/var/lib/mysqld/` neither .pid or .sock file are there.

Comment: Can't you get rid of DirectAdmin? Web control panels tend to make nonstandard and unsupportable servers.

Comment: No, I provide webhosting.

Comment: `/var/log/mysqld.log` would probably have the cause listed.

Comment: What should I look for? Loads of text in there

Comment: Pastebin of my log file. Do you get wiser of this? http://pastebin.com/fsfdc1dd

Comment: try start mysql with `innodb_force_recovery=4` and `innodb_purge_threads=0` in your `my.cnf`, then create the data base dumps

Comment: Can we chat on Skype? I have a few questions if you don't mind.

Comment: I'm sorry, at this time I can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837653/cannot-start-mysql

Comment: I'm in the chat right now

Comment: What are the specific permissions on /var/lib/mysqld?  What is the uid/gid that is running mysqld?  There probably is a conflict here.  Also what is the specific permission of the socket file AFTER MySQL starts running?

Comment: [Administration panels are now off-topic on Server Fault, per the topicality page](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that MySQL is not starting because it "touches" that file when it starts, and it's the failsafe to bail out if that file is already present. Try removing that file.

```
# rm /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# service mysqld restart
```

I've seen that same error before and removing that file fixed it for me every time.

Comment: I have removed the file, but when I restart the service the file is not created and leaves me stuck with the same error. Any clues?

Comment: Maybe make sure that the first file and '/var/lib/mysql/hostname.pid' are still both gone, get your my.cnf and everything else back to how it was before you started troubleshooting, then reboot the server.

Comment: Edited the original post with output after reboot

Comment: OK, now delete this file if it exists:
`/var/lock/subsys/mysqld` and then restart mysqld once more.

Comment: mysqld does not exist in that folder, but mysql does. Should I delete that file?

Comment: Yeah, try that one.

Comment: I deleted that file, restarted mysqld but see no changes.

Comment: what does your mysqld.log show? anything applicable to this issue?

Comment: also, does this file still exist? `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

Comment: That file never existed. Pastebin for my .log file: http://pastebin.com/fsfdc1dd (if you need more lines let me know)

Comment: Have you got skype? Easier to chat

Comment: I'm not going to be much help at this point - maybe needs to have a database repair done via command line. Something [like this maybe?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html)

Comment: Would it help if you could take a look at it yourself? I really need to get this working ASAP.

Comment: mysqldump outputs the same error: mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect